# RJ45 Type Connector With 10 Lines

Tags: wiring, rj45

What is the name of the connector that is similar to an RJ45 but instead of eight lines, it has ten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RJ50**

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector)

> The 10P10C connector is commonly referred to as an RJ50 connector,
>   although this was never a standard registered jack in the Universal
>   Service Order Codes. The 10P10C has 10 contact positions and 10
>   contacts.
>
> The most common uses of the 10P10C connector are in proprietary data
>   transfer systems,[19] such as the Digiboard[20] and Equinox
>   Super-Serial multi-port TIA-232 adapters.[20] 10P10C connectors are
>   also used to implement RS-485 interfaces, and for data link
>   connections in APC and Eaton uninterruptible power supplies. In the
>   latter case, a keyed 10P10C plug with a protrusion on the pin 1 side
>   near the back is used.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the connectors commonly used for Ethernet, the "correct" name for an RJ45 connector is [8P8C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C). So a ten-position connector would be [10P10C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#10P10C) often incorrectly referred to as RJ50.

The RJ standards are for telephony and, though similar, are [mechanically incompatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ45S).

Comment: Technically if the pins of an RJ45 male connector and an RJ50 female connector are both centrally distributed (and thus align) then you can often use the two together. However, this is uncommon, and not recommended even when that's the case, as it could lead to damaging the device, the female connector, the male connector, or all three.